# Dagger 2 - Dependency between SubComponents

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm working on an Android project with several scopes so I organized something like this:

```
@Scope
public @interface @ScopeA {}

public class ElementA {
    @Inject
    DependencyAa dependencyAa;
}

@Module
public class ElementAModule {
    private ElementA elementA;

    public ElementAModule(ElementA elementA){
        this.elementA = elementA;
    }

    @ScopeA
    @Provides
    public ElementA providesElementA(){
        return this.elementA;
    }
}

public class ElementB {
    @Inject
    DependencyB dependencyB;
}

@Module
public class ElementBModule { 
    private ElementB elementB;

    public ElementBModule(ElementB elementB){
        this.elementB = elementB;
    }

    @ScopeA
    @Provides
    public ElementB providesElementB(){
        return this.elementB;
    }
}
```

Long story made short, I've several elements ( A,B ), each one has a dependency ( A,B *respectively* ), which are injected. So my question is, **What is the best approach for this kind of dependency?**

One subcomponent for each Element that inclues a general module for all the Dependencies.

```
@Module
public class DependenciesModule {

   @ScopeA
   @Provides
   public DependencyAa providesDependencyAa(){
        // return DependencyAa
   }

   @ScopeA
   @Provides
   public DependencyB providesDependencyAb(){
        // return DependencyB
   }

}

@ScopeA
@Subcomponent(modules = { ElementAModule.class , DependenciesModule.class })
public interface ElementASubcomponent {
    void inject(ElementA elementA);
}

@ScopeA
@Subcomponent(modules = {ElementBModule.class , DependenciesModule.class})
public interface ElementBSubcomponent {
    void inject(ElementB elementB);
}
```

One general Element subcomponent, which depends on a general dependencies module. How would this work with the custom scope?

```
@ScopeA
@Subcomponent(modules = {ElementAModule.class , 
    ElementBModule.class , DependenciesModule.class}){

    void inject(ElementA elementA);
    void inject(ElementB elementB);

}
```

One subcomponent for each Element, which dependends solely on a ElementXModule, in which the corresponding dependency is provided

```
@Module
public class ElementAModule {
    private ElementA elementA;

    public ElementAModule(ElementA elementA){
        this.elementA = elementA;
    }

    @ScopeA
    @Provides
    public ElementA providesElementA(){
        return this.elementA;
    }

    @ScopeA
    @Provides
    public DependencyAa providesDependencyAa(){
        // return DependencyAa
    }
}
```

Also any other suggestions are more than welcome?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be 2 questions here: how to organize modules and how to work with scopes.

How to organize your instances of `Module` would depend on how the dependencies are related if, indeed, they are related at all. There is probably not enough information provided here to determine exactly but you could ask yourself:

Is there any chance that `DependencyA` and `DependencyB` will be used together to construct any `Element`, say, `ElementC`? If not, they should probably be in separate modules. Unless, of course, there is some sort of similarity of use case that you would like to group together in a logical whole. For example, you might like to group all of the dependencies related to persistence together in one module.

With your second question, as you move down the object graph using subcomponents you can only move from a wider scope to a narrower scope. So, in the top component you might have the singletons for your application. Then in a subcomponent with a narrower scope, perhaps the dependencies for an activity. "Sibling" scoped components cannot access members from each other but can access exposed members from the parent component.

A good example of an Android project using scopes can be found [here](https://github.com/vinc3m1/nowdothis).
In this case, they have grouped dependencies into modules by use case.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand

Comment: " 'Sibling' scoped components cannot access members from each other but can access exposed members from the parent component." I believe, you mean all members of the parent component only, because sibling `Subcomponent`s can access each other's bindings as per second paragraph https://dagger.dev/subcomponents.html